# how to get total order price using mysql?

Tags: mysql

there are two tables one is order and 2nd one is order_details respectively,

**`order`** table

```
order_id    order_name
1           shoes
2           wallet
3           socks
4           bats
```

**`order_details`** table

```
order_details_no  order_id(foregin key)  order_price
        1              1                   25
        2              1                   55
        3              2                   65
        4              4                   30
        5              4                   60
```

My question is, I want result set which includes order_id, order total price in ascending order (eg order 1 total is 80,order 4 total is 90 )

How to get this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select order_id, 
       sum(order_price) as total_sum
from order_details
group by order_id
order by total_sum asc
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Select 
    order.order_name, 
    sum(order_details.order_price) as price 
from order 
     join order_details 
       on order_details.order_id=order.order_id 
group by 
    order.order_id 
order by 
    price desc
```